# MyISAM table with key_block_size set

Tags: mysql, key, size, block, myisam

We have a MySQL server with AWS RDS (version 5.6.34). We use MyISAM tables exclusively. I tried to change key_block_size to increase IO throughput. However, there were two unexpected outcomes.

1> If the key_block_size is set at the index level (eg. 8192), then when the execution completes, the table is turned in to InnoDB, which is not what I want. To change the table back to MyISAM, I have to drop the index(es).

2> If the key_block_size is set at the table level (eg. 16384), then it takes a long long time to build indexes. The time taken is at least many time longer than if the table was left with key_block_size not set.

Any thoughts on what might have happened and why? Should I play with the value, ie. key_block_size, for MyISAM tables?

Thank you very much for any insight.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. 1) should not change the table to InnoDB (actually, InnoDB does not support `key_block_size` per index). For 2) it's not clear which indexes take more time: new or existing ones? If you change the table setting, the whole table has to be rebuilt, so it will take more time than to add a single index. So can you be more specific: add the (or rather: a small sample) `create table` statement, the commands you ran and the resulting `show create table`. Generally: on the checklist to improve performance, `key_block_size` is entry 142. Have you done 1-141 already?

Comment: MyISAM is soon-to-die.  I have never heard of anyone successfully changing key_block_size.  There is no support.

Comment: @Solarflare, running the following statements in AWS RDS will result in converting the MyISAM table to an InnoDB table: 
CREATE TABLE `test_tbl1` (
  `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `row_detail` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `idx` (`row_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `test_tbl1` 
DROP INDEX `idx` ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx2` USING BTREE (`row_id` ASC)  KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8192;

Comment: @Solarflare, I've tried quite a number of optimisation techniques to speed up queries. Playing with key_block_size was to respond to one engineer from AWS who noticed that our IO read is always at 4KB. If we have 5,000 IO per second, we can only do 20MB as the read throughput. Some of our index files are bigger than 3GB (with only two indexes in it). If you have a checklist on all optimisation techniques could you please share with me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RickJames, it's interesting to hear your comment about MyISAM is soon to die. We choose MyISAM over InnoDB because our objectives are solely for analytics, not for on-line transactions. Would like to hear your thought on the main stream/upcoming database engines. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Solarflare, the statement below will set the key_block_size at the table level, which would not triggering the conversion of a MyISAM table to InnoDB. 
ALTER TABLE `test_tbl1` 
ENGINE = MyISAM KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=16384;
However, after setting key_block_size (to 16k), to build an index on the table will take a long time (multiple times longer than the same table if the key_block_size was left untouched). Hope to get some insight from you. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The default key block size is 1K.  The OS likes 4K.  If your index accesses are *random*, smaller is better.  If you do *range* scans in the index, bigger is better.

Making the `key_buffer_size` too large takes away from caching of *data*.  Making it too small leads to more I/O for indexes.  Have you accidentally tipped this balance?

I have never heard of the `ENGINE` being automatically changed.  Please provide more details.  Your test case in the Comments comes back with a MyISAM table for Percona's 5.6.22-71.0-log, and it did keep `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8192`.  (I did not try AWS.)  Oh, I think I found it:  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%engine%';`  Hmmm... Changelog for Percona 5.7.10-1 says: "Running `ALTER TABLE` without specifying the storage engine (without `ENGINE=` clause) or `OPTIMIZE TABLE` when `enforce_storage_engine` was enabled could lead to unrequested and unexpected storage engine changes. If done for a system table, it would circumvent regular system table storage engine compatibility checks, resulting in crashes or otherwise broken server operation. Bug fixed #1488055."

There is a tricky way to get MyISAM to rebuild indexes via "sorting" instead of via "key_buffer". (`SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows you which it is doing.)  (And it says it is "reparing".)  "Sorting" is usually a lot faster, and avoids the key_buffer.

Check the value of `delay_key_write`.

In MyISAM, the `PRIMARY KEY` counts as another index.  I InnoDB, it is clustered with the data, so does not show up in `Index_length`.

There are a lot of optimization and I/O tips.  *But* they are dependant on the queries more than the tuning.  Please provide the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, RAM size, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also, let's see `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`.

If you would like more critique, provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.

Analytics -- Perhaps "Summary tables" is the way to go?  Sometimes that gives 10x performance boost.

Analytics -- when you can scan via the clustered PK, you get better performance with InnoDB than with MyISAM, which has to bounce back and forth between the separate index and the data.  And/or has to make a separate sort pass.

Oracle has kept improving InnoDB by so much that they declare that it is better than MyISAM in virtually all situations.  The remaining deficiencies:  disk space; count(*) without where; 2-part PK.  (Without seeing your analytics, I cannot say whether InnoDB will really be faster for you.  Nor can they.)